# Minimum-cut with Maximal number of edges

Tags: network-flow, minimum-cuts

My question is: in a DAG, each edge has a different value of capacity, we can assume these capacities are integers multiples of the total number of edges. Also, sometimes we can have many minimum cuts, but these cuts have a different number of edges, how can we know which cut has the maximal number of edges?

Comment: Remove $\epsilon$ from each weight, for small enough $\epsilon$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minimum-cut with minimum number of edges](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/115159/minimum-cut-with-minimum-number-of-edges)

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thanks for the response, I have seen this link to find the minimum cut with the minimum number of edges. By removing small e, do you mean  C * (|E| + 1) + 1 instead of + 1, I need to change it into  C * (|E| + 1) - 1?

Comment: You can do it in various ways. I’ll let you work it out.