# Finding the cut with the minimum number of edges (including reverse ones)

Tags: algorithms, graphs, network-flow

I do not know how to solve the following problem:

Given a directed graph $G$ with a two nodes $s,t \in V(G)$ find a cut $(S,T)$ with $s \in S$ and $t \in T$ such that $(S,T)$ has the minimum number of edges **with the "reverse edges", i.e. the edges in $(T,S)$, also counted**.

I realise that, **when the reverse edges are not taken into account**, this problem can be reduced to the problem of finding the min cut with the least edges in an arbitrary flow network, which was already discussed [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/115159/minimum-cut-with-minimum-number-of-edges), by setting all capacities to $1$.

But I do not see how I could include the reverse edges. Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: It sounds like if you use the max flow algorithm, the flow is allowed to run both forwards and backwards.  Kind of like the edges are non-directed?

Comment: @PålGD So basically make the graph undirected and find min-cut using max flow algorithm. That should suffice, right?

Comment: @InuyashaYagami: Yeah that's right.